# Product variation and parent variable product objects in WooCommerce hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I developed a custom delivery time info for variations. But for some reason, I can't get the parent product id of the variation to use it in my function. I tried the following - if I set $id straight to 51237, my code works, but with using $post to get the id, it doesn't.
Any help appreciated!

```
// here I am loading special infos for each variation

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_products_fields', 1 );
function load_variation_products_fields( $variations ) {
    $variations['variation_cmpzDeliveryTime'] = get_delivery_time( $variations[ 'variation_id' ] ) ;
    return $variations;
}


function get_delivery_time ( $product_id) {
    $product_obj = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    

    // here I want the post ID (so the parent product ID if the product type is variation)
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID; 

    var_dump ($id); // this outputs "int(51237)" for each variation - that seems to be right!

    switch($product_obj->get_type())    {
        case 'variation':
            if (Helpers::get_product_multi_inventory_status($product_id) == 'no' ) {
                $_pf = new WC_Product_Factory(); 
                $_product = $_pf->get_product($product_id);
                $stock_status = $_product->get_stock_status();
                if ( wc_gzd_get_product( $product_id )->get_delivery_time_html() == '' )    { 
                    if ( ($stock_status == 'instock')   )   {
                        // $id is ignored - if I put here 51237, it works!
                        return set_delivery_text('instock', $id); 
                    } else  {
                        return set_delivery_text('outofstock');
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif (Helpers::get_product_multi_inventory_status($product_id) == 'yes' ) {
                return get_delivery_time_multi_inventory($product_id);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some missing arguments in your function hooked in `woocommerce_available_variation`… You need to replace it by:

```php
// here I am loading special infos for each variation
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_products_fields', 10, 3 );
function load_variation_products_fields( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $variation_data['variation_cmpzDeliveryTime'] = get_delivery_time( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) ;
    return $variation_data;
}
```

Now as you can see there is 3 arguments, where `$product` is the parent variable product object and `$variation` is the product variation Object.

So you will change you will also have to change `get_delivery_time()` function code something like:

```php
function get_delivery_time ( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $variation_id      = $variations['variation_id']; // or $variation->get_id();
    $is_in_stock       = $variation['is_in_stock']; // is variation "in stock"
    $parent_product_id = $product->get_id(); // The parent variable product Id
    // var_dump($parent_product_id);

    if ( Helpers::get_product_multi_inventory_status($variation_id) == 'no' ) { 
        if ( wc_gzd_get_product( $variation_id )->get_delivery_time_html() == '' )    { 
            if ( $is_in_stock ) {
                return set_delivery_text('instock', $parent_product_id); 
            } else  {
                return set_delivery_text('outofstock');
            }
        }
    } else {
        return get_delivery_time_multi_inventory($variation_id);
    }
}
```

it should work better.

Comment: Ok, your code works better than my code, thanks. So, it is obviously not possible to access $post within the woocommerce_available_variation hook?

Comment: @m3rlin Yes you can try access it using `global $post;` or for sure using `$post = get_post( $product->get_id() );`… you will get the parent variable product WP_Post object. I am curious, why do you need the post object?

Comment: just asking... I wasted so much time trying to find out why it doesn't work, so I wanted to know :) but your solution is better

Comment: @m3rlin When using hooks, always check what arguments are available in the hooked function, you will lose much less time: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L363-L392